# Realm Swift EXC_BAD_ACCESS During Segue with Unpersisted Object

Tags: ios, swift, segue, swift2, realm

I've got an app that I've started adding [Realm](http://realm.io) to and I think I must be doing something wrong because I keep running into EXC_BAD_ACCESS when passing unpersisted objects between view controllers.

Here's a stripped down version of my app.

```
class TodoTask: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""
    let steps = List<Step>()

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}

class Step: Object {
    dynamic var name: String = ""

    convenience init(name: String) {
        self.init()
        self.name = name
    }
}

class TodoListController: UIViewController {
    let todos = List<TodoTask>()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var t1 = TodoTask(name: "Todo1")
        let steps = [
            Step("Do this"),
            Step("Do that"),
        ]
        t1.steps.appendContentsOf(steps)

        var t2 = TodoTask(name: "Todo2")
        let steps = [
            Step("Do these"),
            Step("Do those"),
        ]
        t2.steps.appendContentsOf(steps)

        todos.appendContentsOf([t1, t2])
        // Display table of todos.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let detailsController = segue.destinationViewController as? TodoDetailViewController,
            let selectedTask = getSelectedTask() {
            detailsController.task = selectedTask
        }
    }
}    

class TodoDetailViewController: UIViewController {
    var task: TodoTask?   // <<< EXC_BAD_ACCESS

    // Display the task's steps.
}
```

Unfortunately, I can't figure out what triggers the EXC_BAD_ACCESS and it happens intermittently. I didn't copy a stacktrace (d'oh!) but I remember it being in the C++ destructor for some sort of Row object. This is odd to me because there doesn't seem to be a database file in my Documents folder.

I'm pretty confident this is a Realm-based error because I experienced no weird crashes until I converted my plain Swift objects to Realm objects.

My only hunch is that I might be using List wrong since the warning `This method can only be called during a write transaction.` is in the comments of the `appendContentsOf` method. However, I was under the impression that I could use Realm objects that weren't stored in a Realm just like normal Swift objects.

Am I using Realm objects wrong? Is there anything else I can look into?

I'm on Realm 0.95.2.

Thanks!

Edit:

```
func getSelectedTask() -> TodoTask? {
    if let index = taskTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
        return tasks[index]
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: you missed one } in the prepareForSegue after the if. but i think its not really happen in your code. I would like to see the function getSelectedTask. Maybe here is something wrong. Will prepareForSegue called in the begining? Could be called with an Container with embedded view.

Comment: @BjörnRo I added the implementation of getSelectedTask. It's retrieving the appropriate TodoTask based on which row was selected in the tableview. TodoListController is in a navigation controller, but isn't otherwise embedded. I believe the if let guards against cases where prepareForSegue is called before tasks is populated.

Comment: hmm, you should check if the index exists in the tasklist ... this can lead to crashes. Just check if index is < taskList.count . could fix a possible crash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that a Realm `List` should not be created directly. This class is only used to manage to-many relationships on `Object` models. Instead, you should use a standard Swift array to store the unpersisted Realm `Objects`.

So switch:

`let todos = List<TodoTask>()`

to

`let todos = [TodoTask]()`

Comment: Ah, interesting. Is my use of `List` in my `TodoTask` class ok? (e.g. using `appendContentsOf` in my controller.) Thanks!

Comment: Yes, your use of `List` on TodoTask is the correct use of it. In this case you do not ever directly create the `List` since it is simply a property and the `Object` superclass internals handle its creation.

Comment: Okay, that's good to hear. However, appendContentsOf (and most other mutating methods) has a warning: "This method can only be called during a write transaction." Does that only apply to persisted objects?

Comment: If the base object, such as a `ToDoTask` hasn't been added to a Realm (i.e. it is not persisted), then you can add objects to a `List` property, such as the steps property in your example, without being in a write transaction.

Once the base object has been added, mutating the `List` object to add more objects, will require a write transaction because these objects will then become persisted too.